# JavaScript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default view') . I'm using WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, automation, salesforce, undefined, webdriver-io

Automating tests against salesforce lightning using Webdriver IO. As soon as I perform a click on the home page an exception is thrown as:
**JavaScript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default view') . I'm using WebdriverIO **

I want the click to happen without any error
[DOM Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxuVI.png)

I'm using below code to perform a click:

```
let ele = ("//a[title='Relationships']/span")
await ele.click()
```

Comment: Can you add some of the code you've tried?

Comment: What are you trying to read "default view" from? What is its value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.